# Translation of "Birds of a feather flock together" to Spanish

Tags: traducción, proverbios

I'm curious to know what the translation would be for this quote:

> Birds of a feather flock together.

I'm looking specifically for the translation that holds value and significance rather than a literary one, which occasionally doesn't make sense. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As this is not exactly your question, I'll write this as a comment. The expression *They are birds of a feather* would translate as *Son tal para cual*.

Answer (score 6):

- *[Dios los cría y ellos se juntan](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58529&Lng=0)* ("God creates them and they come together") has a similar meaning, but it is often used in a negative sense. It is used to refer to people that have similar characters or behaviors and come together to engage in such behavior.
- *[Dime con quién andas y te diré quién eres](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58521&Lng=0)* ("Tell me who you spend your time with, and I will tell you who you are") has a similar meaning: you can guess someone's habits or preferences by knowing those of their friends.

Answer (score 0):

I searched online and got this entry.  I'm not sure whether it's widely used or not.

Pájaros de un mismo plumaje vuelan juntos.

It appears to be a direct counterpart of the English saying.

[see proverbios](https://los-proverbios.com/pajaros-de-un-mismo-plumaje-vuelan-junto.html)

Comment: Never heard it in Spanish. It looks like just a literal translation.

Comment: Neither have I.  I don't know what made them include it in a list of proverbios.